# smtp.gmail.com - not working from the website - Hostgator server

Tags: c#, email

I am using the below code to send email using google smtp details. This code works fine on my local machine but not working from the website/server.

- I am using `Hostgator` server and I have already contacted them with no luck.
- I don't want to use Hostgator service for sending mails.

```cs
using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    message.From = new MailAddress(("googleid"), "Test Label");
    message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Host = smtp.gmail.com;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(("googleid"), ("googlepass"));
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;    
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: See website : https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/smtp-settings

Comment: I sound like it works on home network but not on a company network.  Most corporate networks forward all email (port 587) to a proxy server to verify the credential are for an Outlook Email Server on the corporate network.  So any emails going to a 3rd party email will not work.,

Answer (score 0):

Hostgator support team created SPF records, that helped fix the issue.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en

Comment: SPF records will help with whether the receiving ISP sends your email to spam (or perhaps discards it entirely), but it will not affect whether your email is sent. Your question isn't clear about what "not working" means. For future questions, try to be more specific about what is actually working or not working (error messages, etc).